# Undefined reference errors in RTI DDS when using modern c++ API

Tags: c++, rti-dds

**I generated RTI code using:**

```
/opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.0/bin/rtiddsgen -d GENERATED_CODE_DIR -language C++11 -replace IDL_DIR
```

**My CMake file:**

```
link_libraries(gsl gslcblas nnz12 occi clntsh dl nddsc nddscpp2 pthread)
add_definitions(-DRTI -DRTI_64BIT -DRTI_LINUX -DRTI_UNIX -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG)
include_directories(-isystem /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.0/include/ndds)
include_directories(-isystem /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.0/include/ndds/hpp)
include_directories(-isystem /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.0/include/ndds/hpp/rti)
include_directories(-isystem /opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.0/include/ndds/hpp/dds)
```

Now when compiling, I am getting following errors:

```
undefined reference to `rti::domain::register_type_plugin(dds::domain::TDomainParticipant<rti::domain::DomainParticipantImpl>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, PRESTypePlugin* (*)(), void (*)(PRESTypePlugin*))'
undefined reference to `dds::core::PreconditionNotMetError::PreconditionNotMetError(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there anything I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the difference in ABIs of RTI libraries and the occi.so.
Solved the problem by using occi_gcc53.so instead of occi.so library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to ABI. I am using gcc10.2.
I solved the problem by adding definition:

```
_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
```

Comment: It looks more like you have introduced another problem instead of fixing first one.

Comment: @user7860670 Please give a better solution.